# Problem with Upload Speed (ISP or my Fault?)

Tags: upload

i got a problem with my Upload on my Office.
My Office has 2 Servers and some Computers.

I get from my ISP 200Mbit Down and 100Mbit upload. It is an FTTH Connection (OpticalFiber)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glq9f.png)

i think it is capped around 300kbit per Upload connection? And i dont think it is a missconfiguration of a Server because all 2 Servs and local laptops have the same problem.
I already checked:

- The Router (Fritz!Box 7590)
- The Switch (it was an older Managed switch that i changed for testing purposes to an new unmanged switch)
- All Cables (Cat7)

Internal Data transfers are great so i dont think it is the infrastructure itself.

i had iperf connection tests from my 2 servers.
[Server1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKMbW.png)
[Server2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UNHh.png)

and upload tests from my own laptop.
[Lan Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjbb4.png)
[Wifi Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npK17.png)

what it can be?
is it my fault at this point ?
or did the ISP messed things up? (ticket is already open... but yeah they have the same infos and images...)

I would take any advices to check things!

MfG
Blade8895

I expect around 100Mbit of upload :D

Answer (score 0):

Among the many limits to the performance of a TCP connection is:

Throughput <= EffectiveWindowSize / RoundTripTime

If all your upload connections get ~300 kbit/s, and if you run several at the same time and they still each get ~300 kbit/s*, then you should look into what your servers have configured for TCP window size, and what the round-trip-time happens to be to your destination(s). And then look to increase your window size.

*Or the 3-4 Mbit/s your iperf tests implied.  They also suggested some rather small congestion windows (Cwnd) - one of the four "windows" which make up "EffectiveWindowSize" in the formula above - that small a congestion window suggests some non-trivial packet losses somewhere along the way.  Something you could confirm via looking at the network statistics (eg netstat -s under *nix) and/or packet captures.